# Changing "and" to "&" in "abbrvnat" bibliography style

Tags: bibtex

I have trouble finding the right `\bibliographystyle` for my report. What I have now is very close to the ideal using the Harvard citation. Here is my setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} %I have tried {agsm} and {apalike}.
\setcitestyle{authoryear,aysep={},open={(},close={)}} %with agsm "&" is used instead of "and", between author names. 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3] \citep{RefWorks:01}.

\bibliography{souce}

\end{document}
```

This is what could be in my `source.bib` file:

```
@article{RefWorks:01,
 author={C.R. Madan and A. Singhal},
 year={2013},
 title={Introducing TAMI: an objective test of ability in movement imagery},
 journal={Journal of motor behavior},
 volume={45},
 number={2},
 pages={153-166}
 }
```

What I am looking for is for it to say `(Madan & Singhal 2013)`, instead of the current `(Madan and Singhal 2013)`. I have been looking for different solutions, but found none.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `abbvrnat` style hard codes the string `and` as separator between the second-to-last and the last name. Thus, if one is happy  with the way `abbrvnat` formats the bibliography the solution is to modify the style (the alternative is to use `makebst` to create a new bib style with the desired properties).

The procedure is as follows:

1. Make a copy of `abbrvnat.bst` and call it `myabbrvnat.bst`, then
2. change `{ " and " * t * }` in lines 232 and 325 of `myabbrvnat.bst` to  `{ " \myand " * t * }`
3. change  `{ " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }`  in line 1111 of `myabbrevnat.bst` to             `{ " \myand " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }`
4. give a definition of `\myand` in the preamble of the your document, e.g., `\newcommand{\myand}{\&\ }`.
5. save `myabbrvnat.bst` in place where it will be found by `bibtex` (you can put in the same directory as the other source files)
6. replace `\bibliograpahystyle{abbrvnat}` with `\bibliographystyle{myabbrvnat}`.

Comment: I ran into two small problems. 
First I couldn't find the file `abbrvnat.bst`, since I'm working on the online version (writelatex.com because I work in a group), but I made a new file, named `myabbrvnat.bst` and inserted from: http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/abbrvnat.bst

Second, on line 1111 there is only `{ " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }` and not `{ " and " * t * }`. 
So I was not able to get the `&` between two names. The files are all in the same folder (So the `main.tex, source.bib and myabbrvnat.bst`)

Any suggestion what I might have done wrong?

Comment: @user38934 edited the question for the change in line 1111.

Comment: I did as told in the updated step 3 (except replacing it in line 1111 instead of line 111), and now it works.